# Multiple rules in nginx ingress controller not working?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have installed nginx ingress contoller in AKS.

My task is simple. I just want to utilize nginx ingress controller to call my frontend and backend services based on path.

The following is my ingress files.

frontend.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

backend.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backend
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /backend(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-svc
            port:
              number: 8005
```

My expectation:
When I hit ingress controller I want to view frontend application and similarly if I hit with /backend  I wanna call backend API.

When I try the same, Ingress controller is not giving any response. At the same time, If I delete either one of the above yaml file, I can hit the respective service. Bit it's not working when both the rules are applied.

I am a naive user ingress controller. Unable to identify what is going wrong. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: There would be a pod containing `ingress` in a namespace containing `ingress`. Exec into the pod and check the `nginx` config. If it is possible add to the question we could better help you.

Comment: @Andromeda - The file has more than 1000 lines. Could you let me know which part you are interested in this, I will try to paste here.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Add `host` field to both Ingress yamls, and for the 2nd yaml, add one more annotation: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"` to see if it works.

Comment: @YwH - What should be the value for host field?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah any dns hostname you'd like to use, hostname `www.example.com` , for example. After that, you have to set the `Host` header to that hostname for a http request hitting your ingress controller.

Comment: Does the backend has the same host as the frontend, or are they are different e.g. `api.example.com` for backend and `example.com` for frontend? Then you should specify the host in the Ingress file. If they are both on the same host, you have to combine the Ingress files into one, otherwise the first applied config will be used and other one will be ignored.

Comment: Not reproducible with this config https://pastebin.com/raw/FGJ95KXD

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine the rules for both services into a single Ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: combined-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /backend(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-svc
            port:
              number: 8005
```

a different approach by modifying the rewrite-target:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: combined-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /backend(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-svc
            port:
              number: 8005
```

Make sure to delete the existing Ingress resources before applying this new configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I still face the same issue though.

Comment: Let's try a different approach by modifying the rewrite-target annotations (answer updated)